# Woocommerce remove products from search result if they are not in any category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove Products from search result those are not in any category.

I have tried this but this doesn't work.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'products_pre_get_posts');

function products_pre_get_posts($query) {

  if ( ! is_admin() && is_search() && is_shop() ) {
    $query->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array( '' ),
       'operator' => 'NOT IN'
   )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'products_pre_get_posts' );

function products_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {

        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                'field'     => 'term_id',
                'terms'     => get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'fields' => 'ids' ) )
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

In this case function [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) will return an array of term ids excluded terms not assigned to any posts, since argument `'hide_empty'` by default is `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now i am getting this error =>     object(WP_Error)#333 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: And yes my wordpress version is 4.6.1

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce the error, working on my end.

Comment: Doesn't Work with woocommerce 3+

Comment: @Remi updated the answer, works with the current Wordpress/Woocommerce installation.